# How to Always start tomcat with a specified JVM property?

Tags: java, apache, tomcat, jvm, jvm-arguments

I am on Amazon EC2 instance. I started my tomcat using `sudo service tomcat start`. When I did `ps -ef | grep tomcat`, I got the following.

```
/usr/lib/jvm/jre/bin/java -classpath 
/usr/share/tomcat/bin/bootstrap.jar:/usr/share/tomcat/bin/tomcat-
juli.jar:/usr/share/java/commons-daemon.jar -Dcatalina.base=/usr/share/tomcat -
Dcatalina.home=/usr/share/tomcat -Djava.endorsed.dirs= -
Djava.io.tmpdir=/var/cache/tomcat/temp -
Djava.util.logging.config.file=/usr/share/tomcat/conf/logging.properties -
Djava.util.logging.manager=org.apache.juli.ClassLoaderLogManager 
org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap start
```

I want to add another JVM system property `Dlog=/var/tomcat/access/`, and each time tomcat starts by `sudo service tomcat start`, I want it to start with the new property. How can I start it ?

Comment: Usually somewhere like `/etc/default/tomcat` in a Debian Linux - which your service command suggests.

Comment: Or edit it into `setenv.sh`.